# Pie Plot Output Error when try to show in web flask with IO (BytesIO) and Base64 encoder module

Tags: python, html, ajax, matplotlib, flask

I'm trying to make a pie plot with matplotlib library and then try to display/show it on the flask based web page with IO (BytesIO) and Base64 encoding module. But the output showed not as I'm expected. I tried it before in Jupyter Notebook and it worked well, the plot that showed is as i expected.

Here's the pie plot code with the IO (BytesIO) and Base64 encoding module :

```
def plot_input_rumahmakan(df_test_ulasan):
    
    list_dict = []
    list_plot_input = []
    print(list_plot_input)
    
    
    df_testing = df_test_ulasan
    
    list_makanan = df_testing['makanan'].value_counts()
    list_minuman = df_testing['minuman'].value_counts()    
    list_pelayanan = df_testing['pelayanan'].value_counts()
    list_tempat = df_testing['tempat'].value_counts()
    list_harga = df_testing['harga'].value_counts()

    dict_makanan = dict(list_makanan)
    dict_minuman = dict(list_minuman)
    dict_pelayanan = dict(list_pelayanan)
    dict_tempat = dict(list_tempat)
    dict_harga = dict(list_harga)
    
    list_dict.append(dict_makanan)
    list_dict.append(dict_minuman)
    list_dict.append(dict_pelayanan)
    list_dict.append(dict_tempat)
    list_dict.append(dict_harga)

    idx = 0
    for i in list_dict:
        names= i.keys()
        values= pd.Series(list(i.values()))
       
        # Label distance: gives the space between labels and the center of the pie
        _, _, autotexts = plt.pie(values, labels=names,  autopct=make_autopct(values),wedgeprops = { 'linewidth' : 1, 'edgecolor' : 'white' })
        # plt.legend()
        for ins in autotexts:
            ins.set_color('white')
        
        plt.title(f'Ulasan aspek {aspek[idx]} menurut Pengunjung', bbox={'facecolor':'0.8', 'pad':5})

        accfile = BytesIO()
        plt.savefig(accfile, format='png')
        # plt.savefig(accfile, bbox_inches='tight', format='png')
        accfile.seek(0)
        acc_png = "data:image/png;base64,"
        acc_png += base64.b64encode(accfile.getvalue()).decode('utf-8')

        list_plot_input.append(acc_png)
        idx+=1


    return  list_plot_input
```

The plot that i expected is like this (Jupyter Notebook Screenshot):

[Expected Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SdSjZ.png)

It contains all the plot based on  items in "list_plot_input" list.

But when i transfer it to flask web code, the output is like this:

[Output Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rxmNS.png)

It shows same plot but with different colors.

Already check the ajax code and the html code. I think it's not the source of error

Here's the ajax code:

```
$("#test-form").on("submit", function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var nama_resto = $("#nama_resto").val();;
  console.log(nama_resto);
  $(".load-icon-test").show();
  $.ajax({
    data: {nama_resto:nama_resto} ,
    // async: false,
    type: "post",
    url: "/testing",
    // beforeSend: function() { $('.load-icon').hide();},
  }).done(function (data) {
    $("#plot_input_makanan").append(
      "<center><img src=" +
        data.plot_input_makanan +
        " alt='Acc Chart' width='100%'></center>"
    );
    $("#plot_input_minuman").append(
      "<center><img src=" +
        data.plot_input_minuman +
        " alt='Acc Chart' width='100%'></center>"
    );
    $("#plot_input_pelayanan").append(
      "<center><img src=" +
        data.plot_input_pelayanan +
        " alt='Acc Chart' width='100%'></center>"
    );
    $("#plot_input_tempat").append(
      "<center><img src=" +
        data.plot_input_tempat +
        " alt='Acc Chart' width='100%'></center>"
    );
    $("#plot_input_harga").append(
      "<center><img src=" +
        data.plot_input_harga +
        " alt='Acc Chart' width='100%'></center>"
    );
    $("#hasil_input").show();
```

And here's the html code:

```
<div class="card" id="hasil_input" style="display: none;">
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <div class="row" id="table_input">
                                    <div style="font-size: 20px;"><b>Rumah Makan ini memiliki sentimen ulasan sebagai berikut</b></div><br><br>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6" id="plot_input_makanan"></div>
                                <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6" id="plot_input_minuman"></div>
                                <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6" id="plot_input_pelayanan"></div>
                                <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6" id="plot_input_tempat"></div>
                                <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6" id="plot_input_harga"></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

I wonder where's the source of the problem. I really apreciate any response and help from you, Thank You!